# the apex page "myFirstdemo.vfp" is not a legal file name

Tags: html, salesforce, visualforce

I am interested in salesforce. While I have to display a form in visualforce. So, I started a file name called "myFirstdemo.vfp" and am going to save this file name. I get Visualforce page "myFirstdemo.vfp" is not a legal file so how do we write a file name?

Answer (score 0):

According Salesforce documentation about Visualforce pages:

> The name can only contain underscores and alphanumeric characters. It
>   must begin with a letter and be unique, and must not include spaces,
>   end with an underscore, or contain two consecutive underscores.

So, try to remove dot from the file name.

Answer (score 0):

i think the reason why you are experiencing this error is that in your url bar where you are trying to load the page , you are passing an invalid character like &. i just experienced this same error just now and i saw that the error was in the url